# I can't get the location data after permission

Tags: objective-c, core-location

I am trying to access user's location in order to display weather data. I am using this code:

```
if(self.locationManager == nil) {
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
}

// Check for iOS 8. Without this guard the code will crash with "unknown selector" on iOS 7.
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    NSLog (@"ENTERING requestWhenInUseAuthorization",nil);
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

CLLocation *location = [self.locationManager location];
[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
NSString *latitude = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.latitude] stringValue];
NSString *longitude = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.longitude] stringValue];
```

The thing is I get the pop up asking for permission to use current location. I accept but I don't get any location, its value is `nil`. When I go to settings it says I have the permission to access data but I don't get it unless I close the application and open it again. 
Is there a way to get the location at the moment? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You have to define a `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and wait until the location updates (in the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method). This method will be called several times, every one with more accuracy. **There** you want to get your `CLLocation` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the location far too soon. You need to implement the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` delegate method. It will be called when a location is available.

If you just want the one location, you can call `stopUpdatingLocation` inside the delegate method.

Comment: that worked ! 
May I ask if there is something also similar for calendar, after asking permission to access calendar I want to display calendar events but they won't show unless I exit the view and get back to it again.

Comment: That's a completely different question. I would suggest posting a new question with all relevant code and details about that issue.

Comment: I apologise for that I already did and thank you so much for your help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772054/how-to-know-when-calendar-finishes-loading